# Expo Managed Workflow - Modify CocoaPods Podfile

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-camera

### Modify CocoaPods Podfile for MLKit

I would like to implement **react-native-camera** for **managed workflow** which requires **MLKit** for text recognition.

How do I add the following snippet to the CocoaPods Podfile so I can enable text recognition?

```
pod 'react-native-camera', path: '../node_modules/react-native-camera', subspecs: [
  'TextDetector',
  'FaceDetectorMLKit',
  'BarcodeDetectorMLKit'
]
```

### Confusing documentation

[image]

### Yes, it's possible to run native code in managed workflow

1. EAS for building dev build
2. Install the dev build build on device
3. Start dev client and scan QR code on device

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to modify the podfile after build so forked the project and made the necessary changes myself, this way I didn't need to modify the podfile.

[image: commit]